# Vba to find if a string split is null?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an access database, in many of the tables is a field called "Notes".
This field is used by techs to, well, make notes on the equipment.

But these notes need to be broken up into useful groups, as such we've chosen to use "|" as the delimiter. ( . , ; : - _ / \ all have valid notes uses and can not be assigned to this role)

I've tried :

```
If Split(rst!Notes, "|")(1).Property = "" Then
    aNotesOver = ""
Else
    aNotesOver = Split(rst!Notes, "|")(1)
End If

'AND:

If Split(rst!Notes, "|")(1) <> "" Then
    aNotesOver = Split(rst!Notes, "|")(1)
Else
    aNotesOver = Nz(Split(rst!Notes, "|"), "")
End If

'AND:

If Nz(Split(rst!Notes, "|")(1)) = "" Then
    aNotesOver = ""
Else
    aNotesOver = Split(rst!Notes, "|")(1)
End If

'AND I tried: 

If Not IsNull(Split(rst!Notes, "|")(1)) Then
    aNotesOver = Split(rst!Notes, "|")(1)
Else
    aNotesOver = ""
End If
```

None of them work, and I keep getting the "Invalid use of Null " Error.
Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Check for null before you split?

Comment: `ubound(Split(rst!Notes & "", "|"))` will be -1 if the field is empty.  Note the first element in an array from Split is at index zero, not 1.

Comment: So, check the ubound limit and run from there. Thank you.

Comment: Users must remember to enter their new comment with `|` character and not accidentally type over existing text? Bad design. Either use related table for comments where each comment is a record or consider the AppendOnly property of memo type field http://www.mendipdatasystems.co.uk/column-history-memo-fields/4594523656

Comment: @June7 No, the "|" character is put in automatically, used to separate different note fields  that are related. 

So for example:

" Device 95554 has restart issues and 2 HDD failures in the last 2 weeks | 9 GB Used Space | 250 GB Free Space " 

Just as a simple made up example, the only thing the user has to put in is that very first part "Device 95554 has restart issues and 2 HDD failures in the last 2 weeks" 

Everything else is read from a different source, and the delimiter is added in the code.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those unfortunate quirks of VBA. if the passed value is null, then the split function fails.

and if you pass a empty string, then the ubound() value of the array is -1!!!!

So, this is messy.

I would suggest that you build your own custom function:

```
Public Function MySplit(v As Variant, ix As Integer) As String

  MySplit = ""
  
  If IsNull(v) Then Exit Function
  
  If v = "" Then Exit Function
  
  Dim vBuf As Variant
  
  vBuf = Split(v, "|")
  
  If ix > UBound(vBuf) Then Exit Function
  
  MySplit = vBuf(ix)
  

End Function
```

So you could add a delimter to this function.

But, now your code is:

```
aNotesOver = MySplit(rst!Notes, 1)
```

And if the 1 is larger then the number of values, it will still return ""